# Textblocks aren't added?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to generate some UI Elements dynamically. The whole thing works, except it seems like the textblocks are invisible.

```
Grid pGrid = this.createPodiumGrid();

//create textblocks etc
TextBlock bTijd = new TextBlock();
bTijd.Text = currentGig.BeginTijd;
bTijd.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
bTijd.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
Grid.SetColumn(bTijd, 0);
Grid.SetRow(bTijd, 0);
pGrid.Children.Add(bTijd);

TextBlock pName = new TextBlock();
pName.Text = currentGig.Podium.Naam;
pName.Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0);
pName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
Grid.SetColumn(pName, 1);
Grid.SetRow(pName, 0);
pGrid.Children.Add(pName);

Image favImg = new Image();
favImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/thumb.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
favImg.Width = 50;
favImg.Height = 50;
favImg.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
Grid.SetColumn(favImg, 2);
Grid.SetRow(favImg, 0);
pGrid.Children.Add(favImg);

podiumStackPanel.Children.Add(pGrid);
```

The last image, does show on the right location. Am I missing something here? Text color is black on a white background. But I can't see the text. I'm 100% positive that the value is filled.

Comment: You should perhaps remove the `WPF` tag when it is WP8.

Comment: You're right. Replaced it with Silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
bTijd.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
```

You have set the color to transparent by adding the first '0'.

Comment: It verry common to get this type of mistake by typing the others '0' directly after each other.

Answer (score 1):

You have made their Foreground transparent by setting a zero alpha value in `Color.FromArgb`.

Set the Foreground to `Colors.Black` instead, e.g.

```
bTijd.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

or of course

```
bTijd.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Wouldn't setting the RGB to 255, 0,0,0 work? like so
bTijd.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
pName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));

Comment: @Malcor Yes, that does work. And that's the final solution that I've used. Just like VDesign suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

```
pName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

The first parameter of `Color.FromArgb` is the alpha channel. That is, the opacity. And you're setting it to 0, which explains why the TextBlock is invisible. Just set it to 255 instead:

```
pName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
```

Or use the Colors enumeration:

```
pName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```